# Roll-up summary on Lookup Relationship when multi-currency is enabled

Tags: trigger, lookup, multi-currency, roll-up-summary

I have one serious problem which i'm finding it difficult to resolve please help out..!!!

I have Lookup relationship between Account and Opportunity(Custom Object) and i have enabled multi-currency in my org. USD is the default currency, when i select USD as currency in my Account then the rolled up sum from opportunity will be shown properly provided if i select USD as currency in all my related opportunity records to particular Account.

Actual problem arises when i select INR it's not showing the correct rolled up sum

For eg : If there are two opportunity related to one account with INR 60 each, then i supposed to get INR 120 (total amount in Account) in my account but it'll show as INR 2

In conversion rate i have given as USD 1 = INR 60.

Really pissed off don't know what to do please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Have you read posts such as this https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gjPLAAY and its linked idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMq?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a trigger to separately perform the rollup. After inserts or updates of Opportunities build up a `Set` of Account Ids that need the summary field updated.

Then run an aggregate SOQL query to get the sum of the Opportunity amounts for each Account Id in the set.

Finally, write this sum to a custom currency field on each Account.

The sums would all be in the default currency and the UI should correctly perform the currency conversion on the custom Account field.

Comment: Hi all.I tried doing the same .Find the code here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42642/rollup-summary-of-currency-field-using-apex-trigger

Comment: The problem is. the related value value gets converted and shown on the parent