# Getting the right converted currency in SOQL

Tags: visualforce, soql, class

What is the right way to get the converted currency in `SOQL`?

I've got this in my query:

```
      SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name, Id, Name, Include_in_Forecast__c, convertCurrency(Amount) FROM Opportunity
```

HERE's the sample output in my VF page:

[image: VF Page sample output]

I only used 1 `List<Opportunity>` here and a variable for `Total`

Looks like I've got the original currency record from the `Opportunity`.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE : 
My expected total is the sum of EUR(current user's currency) and it's `7939.47`

Comment: So you want to Sum AUD, NZD, and EUR(So you were expecting a total of 18,494.47)?

Comment: the current user's currency and it's the EUR, so the TOTAL must be 3951.50 + 3987.97 = 7939.47.Sorry if the sample image confused you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:D 
So I came up with this solution.

I created a wrapper class:

```
public class OppDispWrapper {
    private Decimal pvtAmount = 0.00;
    public Decimal amount  { get{return pvtAmount;} set{pvtAmount = value;} }
    public Opportunity oppTbl {get; set;}
}
```

This is how I assigned values:

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name, Id, Name, Include_in_Forecast__c, convertCurrency(Amount)/*Amount*/, StageName, isWon, isClosed, OwnerId, CloseDate, ForecastCategoryName 
                                 FROM Opportunity 
                                 WHERE OwnerId in: userSet 
                                 AND Record_Type__c = :'Licence Fee'
                                 AND CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate) = : month 
                                 AND CALENDAR_Year(CloseDate)  = : year];

    totalOppInForecast = 0;
    countOppInForecast = 0;
    for (Opportunity o : oppList){
        OppDispWrapper odw = new OppDispWrapper();
        odw.oppTbl = o;
        odw.amount = o.Amount;
        if (oppCategory == 'pipeLine'){
            if (!o.isClosed){
                oppDispWrapList.add(odw);
                if(o.Include_in_Forecast__c){
                    totalOppInForecast = totalOppInForecast + odw.amount;
                    countOppInForecast = countOppInForecast + 1;
                }
            } 
        }
        if (oppCategory == 'closed'){
            if (o.isWon){
                oppDispWrapList.add(odw);
                if(o.Include_in_Forecast__c){
                    totalOppInForecast = totalOppInForecast + odw.amount;
                    countOppInForecast = countOppInForecast + 1;
                }
            } 
        }
        if (oppCategory == 'cdmCamForecast'){
            if (o.ForecastCategoryName == 'CDM/CAM Forecast'){
                oppDispWrapList.add(odw);
                if(o.Include_in_Forecast__c){
                    totalOppInForecast = totalOppInForecast + odw.amount;
                    countOppInForecast = countOppInForecast + 1;
                }
            } 
        }
        if (oppCategory == 'allIncludedInForecast'){
            if (o.Include_in_Forecast__c){
                oppDispWrapList.add(odw);
                totalOppInForecast = totalOppInForecast + odw.amount;
                countOppInForecast = countOppInForecast + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't mind about the conditions like `oppcategory` and other `if`s. You can make your own condition.
The important code is these:

```
OppDispWrapper odw = new OppDispWrapper();
odw.oppTbl = o;
odw.amount = o.Amount;
```

...

```
oppDispWrapList.add(odw);
```

...

```
totalOppInForecast = totalOppInForecast + odw.amount;
```

Here's a peek on my VF page:

[image]

The `amount` and `total` displayed is the current user's `currency`.

Here's the code on my VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">              
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtOpp" value="{!oppDispWrapList}" var="odw" columns="7" rendered="{!showOppTbl}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!odw.oppTbl.id}" target="_blank" >{!odw.oppTbl.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Owner" value="{!odw.oppTbl.OwnerId}"  />
                    <apex:column headerValue="Owner Role" value="{!odw.oppTbl.Owner.UserRole.Name}"  />
                    <apex:column headerValue="Included in Forecast" value="{!odw.oppTbl.Include_in_Forecast__c}"  />
                    <apex:column headerValue="Stagename" value="{!odw.oppTbl.StageName}"  />
                    <apex:column headerValue="Close Date" value="{!odw.oppTbl.CloseDate}"  />
                    <apex:column headerValue="Amount" value="{!odw.amount}"  />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Hope this helps everybody too!:)

cheers!!!

(ﾉ≧∀≦)ﾉヽ(;^o^ヽ)

Answer (score 0):

The answer you seek is not entirely as simple as you might think. It depends on how your org handles currency conversion. Please see my answer to [Rollup Summary Using Apex Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42642/rollup-summary-using-apex-trigger) for a further explanation of the relevant issues and links to documentation I think you'll find helpful.

Comment: I'll read the link you've shared. Thanks for your help.